# Python - calculating a gradient

Tags: python, numpy, math

If I have some function as array and I want to calculate its gradient then I am going to use the gradient function:

```
from numpy import gradient
g = gradient(f)
```

Then I get that gradient, but If I want to let the gradient to be equal to zero, how can I find the extreme points?

Normally I am not a programmer and I am using Python. I don't understand how to write a function like that yet. It's for my physics project. I understand that if I just write that the gradient equals zero that I will just save the value zero. But when I tried to write that function (million times) I have always failed, mostly syntax problem. Am I right it's going to be 'if' function please? Does anyone has some example? Thanks.

Comment: np.gradient returns the gradient of a n-dimensional array. I don't understand what you mean by f being a function? Refer to the documentation here: [np gradient] (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html)

Comment: I actually meant array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you need the positions where the gradient is zero, you can write something like this:

```
from numpy import gradient

g = gradient(f)
zeros = [ i for i,x in enumerate(g) if x.any() == 0 ]
print(zeros)
```

Comment: I think that is what I was looking for. I am not actually sure what I am doing right now unfortunately, that is why I tried to ask so maybe I would sort my thoughts. And I am bad at programming so thank you.

Comment: And what to do if it returns me just [ ]? Like I need to calculate the gradient of 'f' which is array but with the respect of 'h' which is another array.

Comment: don't use `== 0` for something that can come up a float.  Floating-point errors make exact equality almost impossible.

Comment: actually `if any(g) == 0` is only true if the gradient is zero *everywhere*

Answer (score 1):

Very late; but if you are trying to find zeros, `numpy.where` is perfect for this situation and a lot quicker than iterating the values in a for loop.

You could also index directly. The use case for each is summarised really well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67468682/14764023).

```py
import numpy as np

g = np.gradient(f)

# Method 1 using np.where
index_zeros = np.where(g == 0)
print(g[index_zeros])

# Method 2 using indexing
index_zeros = g == 0
print(g[index_zeros])
```