# boolean indexing vs np.where

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Ok let's say I have a numpy array `arr` and a boolean array `mask` of the same shape (for example `mask = arr >= 20`)

I want an array containing all values of `arr` where `mask` is `True`. I don't really care about the order (I am going to take the sum of this afterwards)

From what I gather from [the numpy doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html), I can just use boolean indexing :

```py
arr[mask]
```

Nethertheless, on the internet, I saw a lot of code along the lines of :

```py
arr[np.where(mask)]
```

Which, I think, does the same, but using index arrays.

Do these two lines really do the same thing ? and if so, is one of them faster ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As for performance: why not simply measure it? Have a simple example:

```py
In [11]: y = np.arange(35).reshape(5,7)

In [12]: mask = (y % 2 == 0)

In [13]: mask
Out[13]:
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True]])
```

Then `%timeit`:

```
In [14]: %timeit y[mask]
534 ns ± 1.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [15]: %timeit y[np.where(mask)]
2.18 µs ± 16.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Unsurprisingly - even if there were no functional differences between both lines - the function call overhead makes `np.where` slower. As to "are they identical"? Not exactly. From `np.where` docstring:

> `where(condition, [x, y])`:
> Return elements chosen from `x` or `y` depending on `condition`.
>
> **Note:** When only `condition` is provided, this function is a shorthand for
> `np.asarray(condition).nonzero()`. Using `nonzero` directly should be
> preferred, as it behaves correctly for subclasses. The rest of this
> documentation covers only the case where all three arguments are
> provided.

Looking back at the example:

While `y[mask]` *directly* selects all matching (`True`) elements of `y`, `np.where(mask)` takes the detour of calculating all (here 2D) index positions for `True` elements in mask:

```
In [26]: np.where(mask)
Out[26]:
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4, 6], dtype=int64))
```

In other words: using the boolean mask directly is not only simpler, but avoids a lot of extra computation.

Comment: Great answer (so upvoted),  But, out of the 2.18 us for `y[np.where(mask)]` isn't only about 0.15 us for function call overhead per [Benchmarking function calls](https://ilovesymposia.com/2015/12/10/the-cost-of-a-python-function-call/)?

Comment: Yeah, I worded that badly. Even *without* any functional difference, I would have expected the function call to be slower. But the majority is probably due to the extra wasted work (calculate 2D indices + retrieve values by them)

Comment: Thanks for the precision ! and for the %timeit trick too